# Second half VBA macro runs 3x faster if i don't run the first part before

Tags: excel, vba, runtime, clipboard

I have two macros:

Macro 1: copy-paste a large worksheet into the same workbook (basically myWorksheet.copy after:=lastWorksheet)

Macro 2: Iterate through data in new worksheet to unmerge any merged cells. Then set the value of all cells in each MergeArea to the value of the original merged cell.

Both macros run as they should.

The problem is the runtime. If I run Macro 1 and Macro 2 in the same 'session' (the way it has to be) Macro 2 has a runtime of roughly 250s.
If I run Macro 1, then restart Excel and run Macro 2, Macro 2 takes only 1/3 of the time (~70s).

I tried clearing the clipboard after running Macro 1 but it does nothing. Otherwise I'm out of ideas.

Macro 1:

```
Sub copySheet()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BigData")

ws.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BigData")

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Macro 2:

```
Sub unmergeCells()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim szArr() As Integer
Dim i%, k%, j%, col%
Dim strt&
'First row
Const fr% = 9
'First column
Const fc% = 12
'Last column
Const lc% = 135 
'Last row
Const lr% = 1196

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BigData (2)")

strt = VBA.Timer

With ws
    For col = fc To lc
        'Some columns only have to be unmerged without changing any values
        If IsNumeric(.Cells(fr - 1, col)) Then
            .Range(.Cells(fr, col), .Cells(lr, col)).UnMerge
            GoTo Skip_Ahead
        End If

        i = fr
        k = 0
        Do While i <= lr
            ReDim Preserve szArr(k)
            szArr(k) = i

            i = i + .Cells(i, col).MergeArea.Cells.Count
            k = k + 1
        Loop

        .Range(.Cells(fr, col), .Cells(lr, col)).UnMerge

        For i = 0 To UBound(szArr) - 1
            For j = szArr(i) + 1 To szArr(i + 1) - 1
                .Cells(j, col) = "'" & .Cells(szArr(i), col)
            Next j
        Next i
Skip_Ahead:
        Debug.Print col & ": " & Timer - strt
    Next col
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Post your code for macro 1 and 2

Comment: How about using `Set ws = Nothing` after copying the worksheet?

Comment: I tried already... Changes nothing

Comment: Did you save the workbook between calling the two macros?

Comment: Yes, runtime remains the same.